# gdalnumeric.LoadFile() with temporary output from QGIS algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to access a previously created temporary raster output with `gdalnumeric.LoadFile()` to calculate some statistics. It seems to me that `gdalnumeric.LoadFile()` can only access a file through a file path and not with a QGIS temporary output.

I tried without success:

```py
import gdalnumeric
path="C:\Users\...\xxx.gpkg"
raster = processing.run("gdal:rasterize", {'INPUT':path,'FIELD':'','BURN':1,'UNITS':1,'WIDTH':50,'HEIGHT':50,'EXTENT':'32351398.3019399,32593108.6666274,5366514.87416986,6045057.7298552 [EPSG:5652]','NODATA':0,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'INIT':None,'INVERT':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
raster_file = raster['OUTPUT']
```

Is there a way to access the temporary raster with `gdalnumeric.LoadFile()`? Or do I need to use a QGIS native algorithm to continue my analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change `'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` to `'OUTPUT':'/tmp/myfile.tif'` and then use `gdalnumeric.LoadFile()` on it?

Comment: `TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` is portable and takes care of working in an appropriate path and with unique filenames.